# "Unpaid" in the operative complaint? What is being paid in an operative complaint?

Tags: meaning

Below is a quote from the judge dismissing the Trump campaign lawsuit in Pennsylvania.  Emphasis mine.

https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/politics/a-federal-judge-threw-out-a-major-trump-campaign-lawsuit-in-pennsylvania-issuing-a-blistering-opinion-refusing-to-disenfranchise-7-million-voters/ar-BB1beNha?ocid=msedgdhp

> "One might expect that when seeking such a startling outcome, a
> plaintiff would come formidably armed with compelling legal arguments
> and factual proof of rampant corruption," Brann wrote. "That has not
> happened. Instead, this Court has been presented with strained legal
> arguments without merit and speculative accusations, **unpaid in the
> operative complaint** and unsupported by evidence."

It is a use of the verb "to pay" I have not seen.  I think "unpaid" refers to the speculative accusations.  I think "pay"  means to give something of worth usually in exchange for something else.   In a worthy case, what would one pay these accusations that here are unpaid?  Or are the accusations themselves what the case should be paying, as one might "pay respects" or "pay homage"?

Or is this the other sense of pay as in "pay out a line" to describe gradually releasing a length of cord or rope?  Would a good case pay out accusations?

Comment: It's either a misquote or obscure legalese.

Comment: I'll note that I've found "unpaid complaint" in a couple of other court documents, so I guess it's legalese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a typo in the article (and in many others). The actual word is "unpled" not "unpaid". https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/gov.uscourts.pamd.127057/gov.uscourts.pamd.127057.202.0_1.pdf

Comment: Yeah, likely this.  I found a handful of cases of "unpaid complaint" in the same context, but many more "unpled".  An interesting point is that some spelling checkers will flag "unpled', but not "unpaid", and may even autocorrect to "unpaid".

Comment: However, there’s at least one case, https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/USCOURTS-caed-2_08-cv-02457/pdf/USCOURTS-caed-2_08-cv-02457-1.pdf, where “unpaid complaint” is intentionally used, involving a jailed pauper lacking finds to make the complaint, which apparently required a filing fee. Thus, not always a typo.

Comment: @Xanne, note that the phrase with the typo was 'upaid **in the** . . . complaint'.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.